# @Singleton bean to read values from ejb-jar.xml

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, stateless, ejb-jar.xml

I have a `ConfigParameter` SLSB that reads configuration values from the `ejb-jar.xml` file.

This class has only private fields and for each field a corresponding getter method. In my application I have a lot of other EJBs that use an instance of `ConfigParameter` to read the configuration values.

Now, I thought it would be good idea to make `ConfigParameter` a `@Singleton`, since its state is shared across the whole application.

But in the `ejb-jar.xml` I can set `session-type` only to `Stateful` or `Stateless`. The file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:ejb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <enterprise-beans>    
    <session>
      <ejb-name>ConfigParameter</ejb-name>
      <ejb-class>myapp.util.ConfigParameter</ejb-class>      
      <session-type>Stateless</session-type> <!-- make this a Singleton -->
      <env-entry>
        <env-entry-name>adminRoleName</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>admin</env-entry-value>
      </env-entry>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

My questions are:

1. Is it a good idea to make this bean a singleton?
2. If yes, how can I achieve this?
3. For understanding: Why is it not allowed to set `session-type` to Singleton?

Comment: Is `ConfigParameter` a simple POJO that only contains primitive and/or String fields that are all retrieved from environment entries?

Comment: `COnfigParameter` was a POJO annotated with `@Stateless`. The field values were injected via `@Resource(name="...")`. I followed Piotr Nowickis answer and I have a Singleton now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using EJBs 3.0. Singleton EJBs were introduced in EJB 3.1. If you want to define it in ejb-jar.xml you should define appropriate version (note the **version** attribute and XSD location changed to **3.1**)

```
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:ejb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd" 
    version="3.1">
```

Or just use `@Singleton` annotation on the EJB class itself.

And yes - I would definitely say that **it's appropriate** to mark application-wide configuration bean as Singleton.

Comment: Thank you! I had my EJB annotated with `@Singleton`, but Eclipse didn't let me use Singleton as `session-type` because of the 3.0 specification. And having Stateless and Singleton definition caused the problem. Now it works. Great.

Comment: @hage glad it worked! However, you know that you don't need to specify it in both - annotations and ejb-jar.xml (one of these place is sufficient), right?

Comment: I know - now :) Someone else in our team created both parts. We're all pretty new to the whole JavaEE and EJB stuff :)

Comment: @hage yeah, these 'someone else did this, so I'll just do the same' are very common :-) In the project I work we had a LOT of `@AttributeOverride` annotations without any reason. Someone needed that in one place and the others just copy-pasted it without a grasp :-) Have fun in JavaEE world :-)

Answer (score 0):

While the  [`Singleton EJB`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119063/singleton-bean-to-read-values-from-ejb-jar-xml#answer-8119135) is a good option, I'd like to propose another idea for consideration. Depending on how many values you need and where they are used, this may or may not be a better approach.

Since your `ConfigParameter` Singleton EJB is just a POJO that retrieves its values from JNDI via the `@Resource` annotation, it may be possible for you to use module or application-scoped environment entries (`java:module`, `java:app`) instead. This could eliminate the need for this extra EJB class; instead, you can just use the `@Resource` annotation within each of the EJBs that needs the values. To do this, just use the `@Resource` annotation within the EJB/web component that requires the value, using a name prefixed with either `java:module` or `java:app`: `@Resource(name="java:app...")`.